# Errors while creating a Single Context Provider in React TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am trying to create a context for Cart by following this: https://github.com/AlexSegen/react-shopping-cart/blob/master/src/contexts/CartContext.js for a React TypeScript project.

I am confused of what does this Context take in as parameters. I am getting errors a multiple places. This is what I have written so far:

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react';
import { CartReducer, sumItems } from './CartReducer';

export const CartContext = createContext({}); <-- 1) Ambiguity Here

type Props = { children: React.ReactElement }

const storage = localStorage.getItem('cart') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) : []; <-- Error1 here
const initialState = { cartItems: storage, ...sumItems(storage), checkout: false };

const CartContextProvider = ({children} : Props) => {
     const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(CartReducer, initialState)
     const increase = payload => {    <-- Error2 Here and for all Payloads below
          dispatch({ type: 'INCREASE', payload })
     }
     const decrease = payload => {
          dispatch({ type: 'DECREASE', payload })
     }
     const addProduct = payload => {
          dispatch({ type: 'ADD_ITEM', payload })
     }
     const removeProduct = payload => {
          dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_ITEM', payload })
     }
     const clearCart = () => {
          dispatch({ type: 'CLEAR' })
     }
     const handleCheckout = () => {
          console.log('CHECKOUT', state);
          dispatch({ type: 'CHECKOUT' })
     }
     const contextValues = {
          removeProduct,
          addProduct,
          increase,
          decrease,
          clearCart,
          handleCheckout,
          ...state
     }
     return (
          <CartContext.Provider value={contextValues} >
               { children}
          </CartContext.Provider>
     );
}
export default CartContextProvider;
```

These are the errors I am facing:

```
// Ambiguity Here:
I am not sure if I can pass an empty JSON object, it might be working for now, but Ideally in Typescript we must pass a parameter type. And I am wondering what Parameter(Interface) this context could take.

// Error1:
var localStorage: Storage
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

// Error2:
(parameter) payload: any
Parameter 'payload' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)
```

In order to fix this, I have tried following approaches:

```
// Fix for Error1:
const storage = localStorage.getItem('cart') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart') || '{}') : [];

// Fix for Error2:
type PropsforPayload = { payload: React.ReactElement }
const increase = (payload: PropsforPayload) => { //Similar for all the occurences.
```

My question here is: Are my two approaches valid? Will they be consistent through out and how do I correctly use the Context for types(interface)

Answer (score 0):

1 - `React.createContext` argument is default value. It's used only when you get context value without provider. If there is no reasonable defaults, you might want to throw error in this case. I use `null` as default value and custom wrapper arround `React.useContext` which throws an error if this would happen.
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext

2 - Typescript doesn't know that `localStorage.getItem('cart')` always returns the same value in this case, so when it's called the second time, typescript still thinks it might be null. So you should save it to a variable first:

```
const cartString = localStorage.getItem('cart');
const storage = cartString  ? JSON.parse(cartString) : [];
```

or

```
const storage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart') ?? "[]");
```

3 -  Typescript have no idea what is payload, so you should specify it manually. Alternatively you can try to use some typescript friendly library to do it i.e. https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#action-helpers